# Cannot Verify Client error 3000 with API problems

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I try to upload my binary to iTunes connect I get error 3000 with heading Cannot Verify Client and a warning, that I ignore if it is connected:

> "The resulting API analysis file is too large. We are unable to
>   validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an
>   informational message"[sic]

In the past submission I remember I needed to create a technical user to submit the binary from it. Yet, apparently things have changed again, as now when I enter that user, Xcode asks me to select another. When I enter the main account it does not complain any longer, but produces that error. I tried both archiving using the "Generic iOS device" option, and my own iPhone 6S with the same result

Please consider each full test may take me more than an hour and so I am weary of testing any possible configuration, even if I already did some.

I succeded once in submitting the app through the Application Loader by tampering with the transporter java file and touching rt.jar. But trying again today I get again the same error. Application Loader is quite vociferous reporting processes locked or already busy. Now I am trying to reinstall Xcode once again, just in case.
May someone help?

Comment: Could you put a link to the original question and relative answer?